# How to connect more than one peripheral BLE sensors - iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on walk analyzing application with BLE sensor. In this I have been working on the single sensor connection and analyze that data. Now I need to connect more than one (up to 4) sensors. What is the best way to connect and manage the peripherals and collect data the data sensors?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep the sensors or CBPeripherals in a list i.e. [[CBPeripheral]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral). You can keep track of read, write, and notify operations on the basis of [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbpeer/1620687-identifier).
E.g. if you perform read operation, in the delegate method you can do:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        
        if peripheral.identifier == YourPeripheral.identifier {
            // Here you are uniquely identifying a peripheral
        }
}
```

Hope this would help.